# Javascript object property is reported as undefined by method called with setInterval

Tags: javascript, methods, this, setinterval

I'm trying to wrap my head around Javascript and want to make a simple web applet that can be enabled and disabled via buttons, and while enabled, draws stuff. To write clean(er) code, I wanted to use an object for this. The setup of the page with the buttons is

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" name="runbutton"   value="Run"   onclick="game.run();"/>
    <input type="button" name="resetbutton" value="Reset" onclick="game.reset();"/>
</div>

<script>
    //...
</script>
```

and the javascript code is

```js
function Game() {
    this.runs = false;
    this.run = function() {console.log('run...'); this.runs = true;};
    this.reset = function() {console.log('reset...'); this.runs = false;};
    this.update = function() {console.log('updating... runs:', this.runs);};
};
var game = new Game();
game.reset();
setInterval(game.update, 300);
```

So it's an object definition (Game) with one instance (game) that has one boolean property (runs), and three methods. One that runs it, one that stops running, and an update() method that reports whether it runs. update() is repeated every 300 ms using setInterval.

**The problem**: the console logs from the update() report the value of this.runs as undefined, instead of false or true. When I open the console and pause it to check the variables, it reports game.runs as false or true correctly. Also, when I add console.log() calls to the run() and reset() reporting the value of this.runs before and after setting it, it seems to report true and false correctly. So the problem seems to be somewhere in update(). It's as if it's using the wrong "this". Maybe setInterval cannot be used on methods?

I tried two other syntaxes for the code, but they seem to have the exact same problem:

```js
var game = {
    runs: false,
    run: function() {console.log('run...'); this.runs = true;},
    reset: function() {console.log('reset...'); this.runs = false;},
    update: function() {console.log('update... runs:', this.runs);}
};
game.reset();
setInterval(game.update, 300);
```

and a version that sets setInterval within the object:

```js
var game = {
    runs: false,
    i: undefined,
    run: function() {console.log('run...'); this.runs = true; this.i = setInterval(this.update, 300);},
    reset: function() {console.log('reset...'); this.runs = false; clearInterval(this.i);},
    update: function() {console.log('update... runs:', this.runs);}
};
game.reset();
```

Same problem.

What's happening? Why does the update() report this.runs as undefined? Am I correct that "this" within the methods indeed refers to the game instance in all cases? Shouldn't I be using setInterval on a method, and instead call a global function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the rules for `this` are somewhat complex; the relevant one is that a non-arrow function stored in an object property can assign `this` to the object if invoked as a method. Let's parse this:

- `game.update` is a property of `game` object, ✅
- It contains a non-arrow function, ✅
- It is invoked as a method... ❌

What does "invoked as a method" mean? It means you invoke a function on `object.property` syntax, like this: `game.update(...)`.

However, `game.update` is passed as a parameter, where it loses the connection to `game`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
var func = game.update;
setInterval(func, 300);
```

where `setTimeout` will just invoke `func()`. This means `game.update` is invoked as a function, not as method, and `this` will not be set to `game` when it is invoked.

The typical workarounds are:

- binding the receiver to the function. This is another way to set `this` beside method invocation described above: if a function is bound to a receiver object, it will always set `this` to it when invoked. You would write it as:

  ```
  setInterval(game.update.bind(game), 300)
  ```

  A variant of this often used in React is explicitly binding functions to the receiver at the place of definition:

  ```
  this.update = function() {console.log('updating... runs:', this.runs);};
  this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  ```
- explicitly use the method invocation, via either of these:

  ```
  setInterval(() => game.update(), 300);
  setInterval(function() { game.update(); }, 300);
  ```
- let `this` be lexically defined, by using arrow functions. Since `this` is the game object at the point the functions are defined, making them into arrow functions would always set `this` to that game object. This needs a change at the point of definition, rather at the point of invocation:

  ```
  this.update = () => {console.log('updating... runs:', this.runs);};
  ```

Answer (score 1):

when you define inside functions using this syntax: `function() {}` then this function will have its own `this`, so `this.runs` will be undefined, if you want this to be an object of the parent function, you have two options:

**OPTION1:** define inside functions as arrow functions:

```js
function Game() {
    this.runs = false;
    this.run = () => {console.log('run...'); this.runs = true;};
    this.reset = () => {console.log('reset...'); this.runs = false;};
    this.update = () => {console.log('updating... runs:', this.runs);};
};
var game = new Game();
game.reset();
setInterval(game.update, 300);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" name="runbutton"   value="Run"   onclick="game.run();"/>
    <input type="button" name="resetbutton" value="Reset" onclick="game.reset();"/>
</div>
```

**OPTION2:** store the parent function `this` as a variable

```js
function Game() {
    self = this
    this.runs = false;
    this.run = function() {console.log('run...'); self.runs = true;};
    this.reset = function() {console.log('reset...'); self.runs = false;};
    this.update = function() {console.log('updating... runs:', self.runs);};
};
var game = new Game();
game.reset();
setInterval(game.update, 300);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" name="runbutton"   value="Run"   onclick="game.run();"/>
    <input type="button" name="resetbutton" value="Reset" onclick="game.reset();"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the context of `this` is not `game` anymore, `game.update` is called as a callback to `setInterval`, if you use arrow functions it will fix the problem.

```js
function Game() {
    self = this
    this.runs = false;
    this.run = function() {console.log('run...'); self.runs = true;};
    this.reset = function() {console.log('reset...'); self.runs = false;};
    // Using arrow function () => {} instead of normal function
    this.update = () => {console.log('updating... runs:', self.runs);};
};
var game = new Game();
game.reset();
setInterval(game.update, 300);
```

Read more about *arrow functions* and *this* [here](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)